# Redirect unsecure websites to a secured website

Tags: security, redirect, web

The website in question takes users to a password authentication page when they click on the members link. After they have provided the correct password it allows them to click on any page, such as a member's directory page. The issue is: when someone just uses Google or any type of search engine, they are able to get to the directory without being prompted for a password.

I am assuming I need to setup all of the unsecured pages to the secured password authenticated one. Could I get some assistance on how to do this?

Comment: Can you add some more information about the content that you are trying to protect?  Is it just a series of HTML documents on your intranet, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: .htaccess files.

Option 2: put an index file (index.php, index.htm, index.html, etc.) in the directory.  If they try to just browse to the directory, they'll get that page instead.

Option 3: If you're using IIS you can set the website so that the directory isn't browsable.

Option 4: You can tinker with the chksum values, but chksum seems to be more of a blanket thing.

There are several ways to go about securing a directory - it depends on your hosting environment and what your expected end-result behavior will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can add redirect code in your .htaccess to redirect your domain from http to https.

A sample code would be like this but you need to modify it if it do not work properly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourwebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourwebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/yourwebsite\.com\/$1"01,L] [R=3
```

Also, in order for your SSL cert to come back clean all external resources / links must come from https or else there will be a small security flag but your SSL will still be active and accepted.

You can google search for additional methods for using .htaccess

Comment: An answer to John Wu's question would be helpful in assisting you also.  What server technology are you using, what kind of software running the site i.e. Wordpress etc.  Details details details.

Comment: Using asp for the password authentication.

Comment: Must of my code is HTML. I am not using any application right now. It is code that I put together from different sources.